# Grouping and regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to isolate the first and the fourth element in the string

```
string = ['Runs_WithWolves || Sat Mar 21 09:38:12 +0000 2020 || Mid December 2019 two friends of mine had caught COVID-19 through work colleagues traveling from Muhan China, but i\xe2\x80\xa6 || 0.7188042218 || false fact or prevention\n']
```

So that it would only return `Runs_WithWolves` and `0.7188042218`.

For now, I have this, but its not working:

```
pattern = "(.+)(?:\s\|\|\s.+)(?:\s\|\|\s.+\s\|\|\s)(.+)(?:\s\|\|\s.+)\n"
for string1 in string:
      print(re.findall(str(pattern), string1))
```

Comment: why don't you just split your string by ||?

Comment: Sorry, but after running your code, I get `[('Runs_WithWolves', '0.7188042218')]`. See https://ideone.com/KdouFA

Comment: You don't need the for loop, just run `print(re.findall(pattern, string))` See https://ideone.com/SMoiwR

Comment: @Thefourthbird Actually, there was a comma after the string in the original post that I edited. I believe OP did not correctly copy/paste a list of strings. So, I edited the `string` declaration.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah ok, I did not look at the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Regex, you can try `split` -

```
string= 'Runs_WithWolves || Sat Mar 21 09:38:12 +0000 2020 || Mid December 2019 two friends of mine had caught COVID-19 through work colleagues traveling from Muhan China, but i\xe2\x80\xa6 || 0.7188042218 || false fact or prevention\n'

new = string.split('||')

print(new[0]) # First Value

print(new[3]) # Fourth Value
```

If you do wanna use Regex -

```
import re

string= 'Runs_WithWolves || Sat Mar 21 09:38:12 +0000 2020 || Mid December 2019 two friends of mine had caught COVID-19 through work colleagues traveling from Muhan China, but i\xe2\x80\xa6 || 0.7188042218 || false fact or prevention\n'


new = (re.split(r'\s+\|\|\s+', string))

print(new[0])
print(new[3])
```

I recommend the way without Regex because it is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) as follows

```
import re
string = "Runs_WithWolves || Sat Mar 21 09:38:12 +0000 2020 || Mid December 2019 two friends of mine had caught COVID-19 through work colleagues traveling from Muhan China, but i\xe2\x80\xa6 || 0.7188042218 || false fact or prevention\n"
parts = re.split(r'\s*\|\|\s*', string)
print(parts[0])  # Runs_WithWolves
print(parts[3])  # 0.7188042218
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try that

```
^(.*?)(?:\|{2}[^|]+){2}\|{2}(.*?)(?:\|{2}|$)
```

- 1st capturing group contains your first  result
- 2nd capturing group contains your fourth result

explanation:

1. `.*?` match anything until it reaches `||`
2. `(?:\|{2}[^|]+){2}` Match 2 occurrence of || and the associated
   result.
3. `\|{2}` Matches the third pair of pipe
4. `(.*?)` matches the fourth result
5. `(?:\|{2}|$)` it matches the 4th pair of pipe or end of  sting.
6. For the first and 4th results, I have enclosed those with capturing groups.
7. `?:` means non capturing group.
8. `^` Beginning of a string
9. `$` End of String

Source Code ( [Run Here](https://ideone.com/IaT8tb) ):

```
import re

regex = r"^([^|]+)(?:\|\|[^|]+){2}\|\|([^|]+)"

test_str = ("Runs_WithWolves || Sat Mar 21 09:38:12 +0000 2020 || Mid December 2019 two friends of mine had caught COVID-19 through work colleagues traveling from Muhan China, but i\\xe2\\x80\\xa6 || 0.7188042218 || false fact or prevention\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    print(match.group(1))
    print(match.group(2))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L8yjIa/1/)

Comment: Not my DV, but `[^||]+` is the same as `[^|]+`

Comment: I can only assume the DV was for the first pattern that you posted, which did not get the desired matches. The current pattern does get the desired matches, but note that the "value" can not contain a pipe char itself.

Comment: You are totally right, it was also in my consideration. Tbh we are always in a rush to answer it fast  before it gets closed with a duplicate link.   If   answering fast is a competition among contributors then now it appears like answering fast before it gets closed is also another competition. lol

Comment: Hey, first thanks for the response! I tried implementing this code, but it just does not work. It returns the same as before which is a list of many [].

Comment: @FafamKurac123 I have added the source code and a link to run it. Please check